# How to use multiple Consumers for a single widget in flutter Provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I can't wrap my head around using **multiple consumers** for a single widget with provider? Suppose my widget is CurvedNavigationBar and I have 4 items in that widget. I also have 4 different classes that extend ChangeNotifier and **are responsible for each item in CurvedNavigationBar.**

**How can I listen to those 4 change notifiers in a single widget**? I looked at the documentation and could not found such an example.. is this even possible? I found that Consumer has a builder method, so that means you can build a widget **only once/and listen to it once.**

Should I rather have a single class that extends ChangeNotifier and then update values in that widget and uses only a single Consumer to listen for updated values?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There are some other `Consumer` widgets. `Consumer2`, `Consumer3`, `Consumer4` till `Consumer6`. If you want to listen 4 ChangeNotifier you can use `Consumer4`

```
Consumer4(
  builder: (context, changeNotifier1, changeNotifier2, changeNotifier3, changeNotifier4, child) {
    // your widget
  }
)
```

Comment: Isn't this kind of a weird design? What if you need 7 or more pieces of state?

Comment: @CameronSima To be honest, I have no idea why it is implemented this way. You can see the implementation in https://github.com/rrousselGit/provider/blob/master/lib/src/consumer.dart

Comment: I've bursted into laugh at the `ConsumN` thing, not because they solved my problem.

Comment: Excatly... @CameronSima what if i need more provider?

Comment: I guess somebody was drunk while coding. Well, it works. Won't complain.

Comment: ```
Consumer<ModelBrain>(
      builder: (context, modelData, child) {
```
how ????

Comment: ah i got it ... i have clicked `Consumer` and scroll to find out of the core thats the different is `Consumer` and `Consumer2` , `Consumer4`. oke thankyou

Answer (score 50):

Yes you can add up to 6 consumers and will be as following

```
    Consumer2<AuthProvider, StorageProvider>(
    builder: (context, authProvider, storageProvider, child) {

    }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to get access to your providers: `Provider.of<SomeProvider>(context)`:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
  final apiProvider = Provider.of<ApiProvider>(context);
  final storageProvider = Provider.of<StorageProvider>(context);

  // Do your usual stuff without wrapping it into Consumer,
  // just pass providers directly to your targets.
  return MyAwesomeWidget(
    authProvider,
    apiProvider,
    storageProvider,
  );
}
```

Comment: I had same mistake like you (include using Builder Widget), please test it, you'll see it work but it has performance issue, the app will slow down at least 33% for 3 providers. I have to vote it down.

Comment: If you are passing objects fetched from provider into a widget, then you should just get rid of all the parameters and call Provider.of<...> within the widget where it's needed to minimize what is rebuilt.